# problemas con UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();

Tags: java

hola tengo problemas con estas lineas de codigo

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UsbException
{
    UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
    dump(services.getRootUsbHub(), 0);
}
```

y java simplemente me da este error

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.getServicesName(UsbHostManager.java:96)
    at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.initialize(UsbHostManager.java:32)
    at javax.usb.UsbHostManager.getUsbServices(UsbHostManager.java:24)
    at usb.DumpDeviceTree.main(DumpDeviceTree.java:3)*
```

Comment: no puedes hacerle .  services.getRootUsbHub() a un null , incluye mas informacion , aqui lo unico que se aprecia es que SERVICES esta en null y a null no le podes ejecutar ese metodo

Comment: O falta el import de UsbHostManager o falta el jar

Comment: si tengo el jar y lo tengo importado